# How do you reference a shell script packaged in your app bundle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, bundle, app-bundle

Given two scripts

> foo.sh
>   bar.sh

copied under */Contents/Resources* in an .app bundle, where **foo.sh**

> `#!/bin/bash`
>   . ./bar.sh
>   echo $1

Do get an error of

> No such file or directory

on the line where the script tries to source **bar.sh**

Is there a way to relatively reference **bar.sh**?

Is there another way to bundle a set of bash scripts in a .app?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

1. get the full path & directory where the actual running script (your foo.sh) is stored. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/3701456
2. call or source the second script (your bar.sh) with directory from 1. (or relative to that  directory)

Simple Example:

```
$cat script2
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello World, this is script2"

$cat script1
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello World from script 1"
echo "Full script path: $BASH_SOURCE"
echo "extracted directory: $(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)"
echo "running script 2"
$(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)/script2 && echo "running script 2 successful" || echo "error running script 2"
echo "sourcing script 2"
source $(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)/script2 && echo "sourcing script 2 successful" || echo "error sourcing script 2"
```

Test:

```
$ls /tmp/test
script1  script2
$pwd
/home/michael
$/tmp/test/script1
Hello World from script 1
Full script path: /tmp/test/script1
extracted directory: /tmp/test
running script 2
Hello World, this is script2
running script 2 successful
sourcing script 2
Hello World, this is script2
sourcing script 2 successful
```

See link above for more in detail discussion ...

Answer (score 0):

Old question but to address the last part (reflecting the current Apple guidelines): yes, you should definitely place all executables (including scripts) in the `MacOS` sub-folder of your bundle:

> *MacOS* - (Required) Contains the application’s standalone executable code. Typically, this directory contains only one binary file with your application’s main entry point and statically linked code. However, *you may put other standalone executables (such as command-line tools)* in this directory as well.

(Source: [Anatomy of a macOS Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19).)

Breaking these rules will prevent you from successfully signing your app bundle for Gatekeer (and, of course, macOS Notarization).

The first part was adequately handled by the other response.